# Kentico - automatic e-mail confirmation - Event Booking system

Tags: events, kentico, email-confirmation

I'm using the Event Booking system in Kentico 8 to manage the registration of my events. Once the visitors register, they receive an automatic e-mail confirmation that is configured in "E-mail template".

I would like to know if it is possible to send different automatic e-mail confirmation regarding the page of registration.

So if a visitor register on a page A, he will receive an e-mail A. If a visitor register on a page B, he will receive an e-mail B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) You can customize your Event invitation template depending on current page. Go to **Email templates** > **Site (global)** > edit **Booking system - Event invitation** template and make your template depending on your document name (or id or whatever). Something like:

```
{% if (CurrentPageInfo.DocumentName == "FirstPage") {"Here is my first email body"} %}
{% if (CurrentPageInfo.DocumentName == "SecondPage") {"Here is my second email body"} %}
```

b) You can [customize E-mail provider](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Custom+E-mail+provider+example)